# jQuery stops working after second keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code works fine when first keyup is made, but breaks once another key is pressed and then randomly works fine after few more keys are pressed and I cant figure out why... My code looks like it should work just fine, but it doesnt...

```
    jQuery("#myid").keyup(function() {  
        jQuery(".myclasss-suggestion").each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).html().substr(0, 2) == "GG"){
                jQuery(this).removeClass("ss");
                jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().substring(2, jQuery(this).html().length));
            }else{
                jQuery(this).removeClass("gg");
                jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().substring(2, jQuery(this).html().length));
            }
        });
    });
```

(It should remove GG and SS from the beginning of each `.myclass-suggestion` and remove either gg or ss class from the item, it does it when first key is pressed, then it stops working)

HTML it is using:

```
    <input id="myid" >
    <div class="myclasss-suggestions">
    <div class="myclasss-suggestion ss gg" data-index="0">GGContent</div>
    <div class="myclasss-suggestion ss gg" data-index="1">GGContent</div>
    <div class="myclasss-suggestion ss gg" data-index="2">GGContent</div>
    <div class="myclasss-suggestion ss gg" data-index="3">SSContent</div>
    <div class="myclasss-suggestion ss gg" data-index="4">SSContent</div>
    <div class="myclasss-suggestion ss gg" data-index="5">SSContent</div>
    <div class="myclasss-suggestion ss gg" data-index="6">SSContent</div>
    <div class="myclasss-suggestion ss gg" data-index="7">SSContent</div>
    <div class="myclasss-suggestion ss gg" data-index="8">SSContent</div>
    <div class="myclasss-suggestion ss gg" data-index="9">SSContent</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you show us your HTML please?

Comment: Is there to much processing happening because on each key up there is allot of looping happening?

Comment: @Hello-World yes, but longest process is on the first keyup, because there are most matches found for one letter, then looping decreases... so I am confused why it stops working, I will try post some html now

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use `.text()` instead of `.html()` . As a matter of fact `.text()` `return`s a `string`, `.html()` `return` the `html` inside the `selector`. So when you do your "second" `keyup` your markup is all messed up, because you're substituing it with a bad-manipulated `string` (which was the `html` markup you got the first time).

As of `jquery DOC`

```
.html()
Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

.text()
Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements
including their descendants.
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Try with :

```
 jQuery("#myid").keyup(function() {  
        jQuery(".myclasss-suggestion").each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).text().substr(0, 2) == "GG"){
                jQuery(this).removeClass("ss")
                            .text(jQuery(this).text().substring(2, jQuery(this).text().length));
            }
            if(jQuery(this).text().substr(0, 2) == "SS")   {
                jQuery(this).removeClass("gg")
                            .text(jQuery(this).html().substring(2, jQuery(this).text().length));
            }
        });
    });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VhtAU/

Comment: It doesn matter if I use `.text();` or `.html();` thye both end up with same result

Comment: added html to original post

Comment: I added fiddle check it out